# How to install Tensorflow on cluster account on CentOS

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, cluster-computing

I am recently reading some deep learning using tensorflow. I was successfully installed tensorflow on Ubuntu 16 in python environment on my laptop and validate this installation at the end and it was successful by following the procedure on [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux). 
In order to take the ultimate benefits from processing capacity, i have taken an account of cluster client running CentOS (Linux based operating system) running under my school to take the large capacity of benefits for their students like simulation etc. And this Cluster system comprises of about 16 cluster nodes with 6 processes. This is all what i know about the cluster environment.
Note: this is not GPU based cluster.

Admin has given me userid and password along with host ip address to access the cluster from any system. I installed one software naming **Xmanager Enterprise 5** under windows operating system. I can access my account now.

What i need to know is that,

> 1. I am unable to install anything without passing sudo command and if i pass sudo command it shows me the privilege error message. How can i install required packages on cluster machine so that i could run my program accordingly?
> 2. Or is there anything else by installing everything locally to my laptop 
>      ubuntu and then converting this to cluster end.

In fact, I want to know something more about it but I am unable to start with. Please guide me.